# Как сделать запрос PHP, MYSQL

Tags: фильтрация, php, запрос, mysql

Добрый день, постараюсь, как можно подробнее расписать проблему. У меня есть таблица Квартира с полями (кол.комнат, этаж, площадь, цена, город). Я делаю выборку из БД на страницу

```
echo GetNav($p, $num_pages);
   $sel = "SELECT * FROM `kvartiri` LIMIT ".$start.", ".$num_elements;
   $query = mysql_query($sel);
   if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
     ?>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="15">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
          <?php
          while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo '<tr><td>'.$res['avtor'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$res['telephon'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$res['etaj'].'</td></tr>';
          }
          ?>
        </table>
```

На странице имеется форма. На форме input'ы. Кол-во комнат, цена, город и КНОПКА НАЙТИ. Думаю, Вы поняли, что я имею ввиду. Так вот, каким образом мне перелопатить запрос. Я понимаю с несколькими условиями, но у меня собственно проблема, а если не введено одно из значений, допустим, заполнены поля кол-во комнат, цена, а город остался пустым.
Тогда в where `gorod=$gorod` будет некорректным.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы совершенно нет. До формирования запроса, проверяйте, какие из полей пришли из формы не пустыми и добавляйте их в запрос, например:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `kvartiri` WHERE 1 ';
// получаем данные с формы (цена, город)
$price = $_POST['price'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
// если цена не пустая, включаем ее как условие в запрос
if (!empty($price)) {
    $sql .= "AND `price` = '{$price}' ";
}
// если город не пустой, включаем его как условие в запрос
if (!empty($city)) {
    $sql .= "AND `city` = '{$city}' ";
}
$sql .= "LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
...
```